# How to use pin to trace memory access of a process

Tags: memory, process, trace

I am using pin to trace the memory accesses of a program.
The following command works as expect:

```
pin -t obj-intel64/pinatrace.so -- ./HelloWorld
```

And it will start the 'HelloWorld' process.

But if I start HelloWorld first, and then attach the pintool to the process via following command:

```
pin -pid pid_of_helloworld -t obj-intel64/pinatrace.so
```

There is no output generated (i.e. pinatrace.out).

Does anyone know how to trace the memory accesses of an existing process with pintool? Thanks in advance.